# sql server procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I am a beginner at using XML with sql server, I have a stored procedure that contains xml file which is used to filter the branch column:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sptest] @Branch_xmlData XML
AS
    CREATE TABLE #Branch
      (
         CompanyID TINYINT,
         BranchID  INT
      )

    DECLARE @flt_Owner_doc INT

    EXEC Sp_xml_preparedocument
      @flt_Owner_doc OUTPUT,
      @Owner_xmlData

    INSERT INTO #Owner
                (CompanyID,
                 OwnerID)
    SELECT C,
           I
    FROM   OPENXML(@flt_Owner_doc, '/Table/T', 1)
              WITH (I INT,
                    C TINYINT)

    EXEC Sp_xml_removedocument
      @flt_Owner_doc
```

and when I try to edit the code to filter another column rather than branch column I get this message when I open the report:

procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Comment: Please show us a sample of your XML, and explain what you're trying to do - you can most likely do it much more simply than using `OPENXML`.....

Comment: There is a syntax error in the procedure as you have given it. You have a comma after what looks like the single parameter to the procedure, and no parentheses around the parameter.  Please check the procedure definition and edit your question.

Comment: Since 2005, OPENXML is not the preferred way to shred xml.  See http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/06/shredding-xml-in-sql-server-2005.html.  Whenever you ask a shred-xml question, you should include sample xml.